# Metro has encountered an error: While trying to resolve module `@apollo/client`

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, graphql

I am trying to install GraphQL into my React Native app and in doing so, I was given this error message.

I have confirmed that the file actually exists and have quit everything and restarted my server and nothing is working. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Metro has encountered an error: While trying to resolve module `@apollo/client` from file `/Users/johnhenryluke/Desktop/sparta-app2/App.js`, the package `/Users/johnhenryluke/Desktop/sparta-app2/node_modules/@apollo/client/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/johnhenryluke/Desktop/sparta-app2/node_modules/@apollo/client/main.cjs`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

- /Users/johnhenryluke/Desktop/sparta-app2/node_modules/@apollo/client/main.cjs(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
- /Users/johnhenryluke/Desktop/sparta-app2/node_modules/@apollo/client/main.cjs/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json): /Users/johnhenryluke/Desktop/sparta-app2/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js (436:17)

434 |
435 |         if (error instanceof InvalidPackageError) {

> 436 |           throw new PackageResolutionError({
> |                 ^
> 437 |             packageError: error,
> 438 |             originModulePath: from,
> 439 |             targetModuleName: to

ABI44_0_0RCTFatal
__37-[ABI44_0_0RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
**CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE**
__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
-[UIApplication _run]
UIApplicationMain
main
start_sim
0x0
0x0

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Metro to accept the `cjs` file extension in your `metro.config.js`

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
  return {
    ...
    resolver: {
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "cjs"]
    }
  };
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is the metro.config.js file in the node modules folder correct? Where am I supposed to put it in the config file because mine has a lot of stuff in it. Sorry, I'm still learning JS